# Change firstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() textcolor when recyclerview scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a recyclerview where the first visible items text color should change when scrolling. ie, the first visible  item of recycler view have different color than other row items. I already tried several techniches but none of those worked. below is snap of my code

```
     mListView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (!getUserVisibleHint()){
                    return;
                }
                int firstVisiblePosition=layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (firstVisiblePosition==mLastReadPosition)return;
                if(firstVisiblePosition!=-1){
                    View view =layoutManager.findViewByPosition(firstVisiblePosition);
                    listAdapter.setViewRead(view,firstVisiblePosition);
                    if (mLastReadView!=null){
                        listAdapter.setViewUnRead(mLastReadView);
                    }
                    mLastReadView=view;
                    mLastReadPosition=firstVisiblePosition;
                }
}
```

this work when I scroll reversely,but not working on forward scrolling. I already searched for libraries in GitHub, If you know any libraries please suggest. Or help me for resolve this>?

Comment: Just a suggestion -> See if `SnapHelper` can work somehow to achieve this . I do not know exactly but give it a try .

Comment: I will try that and let you know

Comment: [Here](https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8) is good tutorial on `Snaphelper` a little customization can make this work. Good luck